# Vsphere san disk best practice

Tags: vmware-esx, storage-area-network, hp

i have a HP EVA 4000 SAN
now, what do you suggest in performance view.
should i cut two 500GB raid 5 disks in the EVA and the do a disk expand in vsphere
or i wont see any perfromance improvements?

thanks for you great tips

Comment: How many drives are in the SAN are available for vSphere? Just two?  Also, give us the type (ssd,sata,sas) size and speed.

Comment: There are 40 15k Fibre optic disks in the SAN in total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extend a datastore the LUNs are merely concatenated rather than stripped so you get no performance improvement.

Comment: Especially on an EVA4000 where the LUNs are all on the same spindles. Due to how the EVA carves out space, both LUNs are occupying the same physical drives so striping won't gain any improvement versus concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 40 15k drives available and are concerned about performance, I would consider creating multiple 2 TB raid-10 volumes.  The max lun size that esx can currently handle is 2 TB -512 bytes accoding to [this](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_config_max.pdf).